# LWC Select component to select value based on specific value in JS not HMTL

Tags: developer, lwc-dom, lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

I have code right now below that selects the value based on the selectedindex of 0 or since I only have two options. What I am trying to figure out is how to set the select value instead of by 0 or 1 by value like male or female

```
render() {
        setTimeout(() =>
          this.template.querySelector('[name="genderfield"]').selectedIndex = 1
        );
        
        return template;
    }

 <div class="nds-select_container">
            <select class="nds-select nds-has-value" name="genderfield" required onchange={handleChange}>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
            </select>
            <label class="nds-form-element__label" for="select-01">Gender</label>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HTMLSelectElement.options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/options) property of the select element to determine which item you want to select dynamically:

```
const genderfield = this.template.querySelector('[name="genderfield"]');
genderfield.selectedIndex = [...genderfield.options].findIndex(option => option.value === 'Female');
```

Comment: The following is getting a couple of errors, 1 where { is expected in the const genderfield line and another declaration or expected statement to end at the last ); I am not sure why 'render() {
            setTimeout(() =>
            const genderfield = this.template.querySelector('[name="genderfield"]');
            genderfield.selectedIndex = [...genderfield.options].findIndex(option => option.value === 'female');
              //this.template.querySelector('[name="genderfield"]').selectedIndex = 1
            );
            
            return template;
        }'

Comment: @DrakeDavenport If you have more than one line/statement in an arrow function, you need to write it as a function body, such as: `setTimeout(() => { const genderfield = this.template.querySelector('[name="genderfield"]');
genderfield.selectedIndex = [...genderfield.options].findIndex(option => option.value === 'Female'); })`